# change generic param name as json property

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

The problem with the wrapper class with generic to get two elements to put in `@Requestbody` in rest controller is, I wanna change the name of the params generic class in my json for each request for example:
instead of param1 and param2 use tableName and colName
and for another request use taskInfo instead of param1 and..
like this:

```
 //wrapper class
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Setter
        @Getter
        public class RequestInfo<T,D> {

           private T param1;

           private D param2;
        }

//usage
  @PostMapping(value = "/addProcess", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createProcess(@RequestBody RequestInfo<HseHTlvRequests,TaskInfo> requestInfo) throws CustomException {
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = reqApplicantService.addProcess(requestInfo.getParam1(), requestInfo.getParam2());

        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

        else
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);

    }
    //in postman
    {
      "param1":"lkp_table_name",
      "param2":"lkp_col_Name"
    }
```

Comment: i tried to @Jsonproperty but it is not a general way for each request for several names

Comment: Why don't you use both set of properties param1,param2,... and taskifo1, taskinfo2,.. on the same JsonClass(DTO). Then you would populate either one of the set in your service level according to your request. And for the client side you are good to go without any changes.

Comment: thanks.but is there any way to use json annotation on generic filed?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to have a single property of a DTO with multiple (dynamic name) by using annotations? And if it's not for multiple but just for two different names then why aren't you using just two different properties? A DTO doesn't have to be a "mirror" of an entity, therefore it's not a bad practice to use one property i.e. for the scenario where you use the DTO for "export" and a different one for "import". Perhaps you should rewrite the question to be more clear.